# Dynamical ng-model in ng-repeat is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I need help with dynamically generated models inside ng-repeat. I have a HTML with ng-repeating table rows. Each row has an option to update image name and price with update button.

HTML

```
<tr role="row" class="odd" ng-repeat="i in slideShowImages track by $index">
    <td>
        <img ng-src="{{i.thumb_path}}" width="100px" height="auto" >
    </td>
    <td>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="imageName" ng-model="i.imageName[$index]"
                   class="form-control" id="imageName" required>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>{{i.date_taken | myDate}}</td>
    <td>
        <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" name="imagePrice" ng-model="i.imagePrice[$index]"
                   class="form-control" id="imagePrice" required>
        </div>
    </td>
    <td>
        {{i.position}}
    </td>
    <td>
        <a ng-click="updateImage(i.id_thumb, $index)">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-success">Update</button>
        </a>
    </td>
    <td>
        <a ng-click="deleteImage(i.id_thumb, $index)">
            <button class="btn btn-block btn-danger">Delete</button>
        </a>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And this is my controller function which is trying to get the values

```
$scope.updateImage = function(id, $index){
    $scope.models = {};
    console.log(id);
    console.log($index);
    console.log($scope.i.imageName[$index]);
    console.log($scope.i.imagePrice[$index]);
};
// result of console logs
4
0
angular.js:13550 TypeError: Cannot read property 'imageName' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.updateImage (locationsCtrl.js:243)
    at fn (eval at compile (angular.js:14432), <anonymous>:4:486)
    at expensiveCheckFn (angular.js:15485)
    at callback (angular.js:25018)
    at Scope.$eval (angular.js:17229)
    at Scope.$apply (angular.js:17329)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.<anonymous> (angular.js:25023)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.dispatch (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:3)
    at HTMLAnchorElement.r.handle (jQuery-2.1.4.min.js:3)
```

Guess i'm doing something wrong, based on error that imageName and imagePrice can't be undefined. I hope you guys can help me. If you need any additional information's please let me know and i will provide. Thank you in advance

Comment: Does your $scope.slideShowImages has a property imageName in each of its object ?

Comment: each object contains same properties as other objects inside  $scope.slideShowImages

Comment: What is $scope.i ?? You can't refer to iterating value in scope like that. You should actually look for $cope.slideShowImages[$index].imageName[$index]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You had `ng-repeat` with `i in slideShowImages` which says that, on each iteration `i` will have current element of collection over the UI only(not in controller scope). So you can not get `$scope.i` value inside controller. You have to pass that value from `updateImage` as a parameter like `ng-click="updateImage(i)"`. Then you can play with `i` object which is available on UI.

**HTML**

```
<td>
    <a ng-click="updateImage(i)">
        <button class="btn btn-block btn-success">Update</button>
    </a>
</td>
<td>
    <a ng-click="deleteImage(i, $index)">
        <button class="btn btn-block btn-danger">Delete</button>
    </a>
</td>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.updateImage = function(i){
    console.log(i.imageName);
    console.log(i.imagePrice);
};
```

Comment: index in i.imageName is not necessary since you are passing whole object as argument in function. Any way it's working. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You cannot ge the `i` object of `ng-repeat` in the controller.
What else one can do is filter using any other key in the json.

Example:

```
$scope.currentImageName = $filter('filter')(slideShowImages,{ id: $index});
```

Here assuming `slideShowImages` has a field *id* of value - `$index`.

Also, add the dependency injection`$filter` in the controller definition.

Comment: Rather than find a currentImageName by filtering, I'd pass i object in the method parameter like I shown in my answer, though this filtering based on `$index` wouldn't be a great option to go.

Comment: @Pankaj, yeah that's a really better idea. Go ahead. And thanks.